# Cannot run react file due to MUI Material problem and can't use npm to install package

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I got these from Terminal when I tried to install and uninstall package by npm :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: <user>@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.6.3" from shards-react@1.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/shards-react
npm ERR!   shards-react@"^1.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

so i cannot use npm to install or uninstall any package which was downloaded now

and compiled problem was :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/index.js 2:0-191

export 'experimental_sx' (reexported as 'experimental_sx') was not found in '@mui/system' (possible exports: Box, Container, GlobalStyles, Stack, StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider, Unstable_Grid, alignContent, alignItems, alignSelf, alpha, backgroundColor, bgcolor, border, borderBottom, borderBottomColor, borderColor, borderLeft, borderLeftColor, borderRadius, borderRight, borderRightColor, borderTop, borderTopColor, borderTransform, borders, bottom, boxSizing, breakpoints, color, colorChannel, columnGap, compose, containerClasses, createBox, createBreakpoints, createContainer, createGrid, createSpacing, createStack, createStyled, createTheme, createUnarySpacing, createUnaryUnit, css, darken, decomposeColor, display, emphasize, flex, flexBasis, flexDirection, flexGrow, flexShrink, flexWrap, flexbox, fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, fontWeight, gap, getContainerUtilityClass, getContrastRatio, getGridUtilityClass, getLuminance, getPath, getStackUtilityClass, getStyleFromPropValue, getStyleValue, getThemeProps, getValue, grid, gridArea, gridAutoColumns, gridAutoFlow, gridAutoRows, gridClasses, gridColumn, gridRow, gridTemplateAreas, gridTemplateColumns, gridTemplateRows, handleBreakpoints, height, hexToRgb, hslToRgb, justifyContent, justifyItems, justifySelf, keyframes, left, letterSpacing, lighten, lineHeight, margin, marginKeys, maxHeight, maxWidth, mergeBreakpointsInOrder, minHeight, minWidth, order, padding, paddingKeys, palette, paletteTransform, position, positions, private_safeAlpha, private_safeColorChannel, private_safeDarken, private_safeEmphasize, private_safeLighten, recomposeColor, responsivePropType, rgbToHex, right, rowGap, shadows, shape, shouldForwardProp, sizeHeight, sizeWidth, sizing, sizingTransform, spacing, stackClasses, style, styled, systemDefaultTheme, textAlign, textTransform, top, typography, typographyVariant, unstable_createCssVarsProvider, unstable_createGetCssVar, unstable_createStyleFunctionSx, unstable_defaultSxConfig, unstable_extendSxProp, unstable_getThemeValue, unstable_resolveBreakpointValues, unstable_styleFunctionSx, useTheme, useThemeProps, useThemeWithoutDefault, width, zIndex)
```

PS. I use @mui/material@5.11.0 and React18.2.0 now

I tried to compile an fix the problem by change the version of package by yarn and change the version in package.json file but it didn't work at all. So how can I fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to switch your **node** version? @sindy

Comment: This is because you installed a dependency that has a different version of the peer dependency than you have. Try to use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` to ignore peer dependency requirement.

Comment: i upvote, but, The problem with that, he is not able to use NPM. So, your answer may not work. @Arnas

Comment: In addition to your suggestion @Arnas. You also use ```npm show shards-react peerDependencies``` for determined the required version of React. Then, you can run ```npm install react@<required-version>```. is the same things as above suggestion.

Comment: According to the npm logs, it can't install and uninstall due to version conflicts of the dependency tree. @DSDmark

Comment: Ya, I agree with you @Arnas, The error message mentions that there is a conflict between the version of dependencies which is ```react@17.0.2```.